# Serialization through different version

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, casting, deserialization

I would like to serialize an object of a custom class, than, after some thing(for example a solution rebuild), I should deserialize the given object.
The problem is that after the rebuild if I try to deserialize is thrown the InvalidCastException...

I think is because after a rebuild the serialized object "belongs" to a different assembly, is this the problem? how can I resolve?

This is the full exception

> [A]UserWeb cannot be cast to [B]UserWeb. Type A originates from
>   'App_Code.1us8pwe3, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\7b743d5e\8394e6b3\App_Code.1us8pwe3.dll'. Type B originates
>   from 'App_Code.nzoq2xtn, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\7b743d5e\8394e6b3\App_Code.nzoq2xtn.dll'.

Theese are my Serialize/Deserialize functions

```
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        bformatter.Serialize(stream, obj);

        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

        return text;
    }

    public static object Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        object obj = bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();

        return obj;
    }
```

The serialized object is stored on the DB.

The exception is thrown just when I try to cast the deserialization result.

Comment: Give more information. How you serialize it? Where do you store it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added new informations

Comment: I see. You need some other serializer.

Comment: What serializer can I use?

Comment: Do I understand right, serializing and deserializing is working fine. Only when you rebuild your solution, deserializing of existing data fails. If you serialize new data, deserializing work on that again?

Comment: If you add/remove data from a class that is serialize any data that was created from old class in no longer value since the size of the serialize object has changed.  If you need to support old and new data then you need to add some sort of version identification to the serialized data so it can be forward/backwards compatible.